# Return the name of active view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview

This all, in my project I need to know the name of my view active at a given time to perform the actions. Let me explain, I have a button inside, and I have to say, "if the view is active viewCpu do something, if the view is active viewTest1 do something else, if it is the other viewTest2 etc etc" but I do not know what function to use for me back the name of the currently active view.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method as there are commonly many views active/visible at the same time. You will have to build such logic yourself.

Comment: ..sorry ,not many view, just one active, but i need a function that return the name of that view (the unique view active in this time)

Comment: again, there is no such function within the iOS SDK. You will have to create something like that yourself.